# Normalize (rewrite) LDAP searches for phone numbers

Tags: ldap, openldap, apacheds

We do store normalized phone numbers (example format: +491511739393) for contacts in our LDAP server.
How can we return the right contact even if we search for "01511739393" or "00491511739393") without modifying the search syntax on client side?

Can we configure OpenLDAP, ApacheDS or even another LDAP server to "rewrite" simple search queries?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Normalise them when you search as well. Same piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LDAP servers such as OpenLDAP, ApacheDS or ForgeRock Directory Services are implementing standard matching rules for the telephoneNumber syntax. You only have 2 options, you normalize the value before searching. Or you normalize part of it and use substring search (for example to match 1511739393, you can use `(telephoneNumber=*1511739393)`)